# removing outliers from the graph in r

Tags: r

[image]

I have a data frame and the red graph is plotting a column versus the datetime column, but it's obvious it is noisy. It should kind of look as smooth as the black plot. Would you please tell me to clean this graph?

Comment: Perhaps take the rolling 24hr avg for the red series. e.g. `df %>% mutate(red_smoothed = slider::slide_index(red_value, datetime_col, mean, .before = lubridate::hours(24))`

Comment: Re(P2_cal)? if doing time series analysis perhaps you can filter the signal or something. Nevertheless, ggplot has `geom_smooth()`  e. g. `ggplot()+geom_smooth(method="loess", span=0.05)`

Comment: Jon, Do you know a method so I can learn more about it? Now I am getting an error! "Caused by error in `stop_slider()`:
! `.i` must be in ascending order.
i It is not ascending at locations: 648, 2888, 3115, 3157, 3164...."